# Selection of Records in a Subform when opening a different form via the Mainform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a subform as a Datasheet inside my Mainform; on my Mainform i have a Button that opens a different Form(frmtwo) as a Dialog; i would like to alter the Records currently selected in the subform via the frmtwo.

What I have so far: the Button opens the frmtwo without Problem and I have referenced the Subform via

```
Dim F As Form
Dim RS As Recordset
Dim length As Long
Set F = Forms![frmMain]![Subform].Form
Set RS = F.Recordset
```

but when I try to determine the currently selected Record of the subform via

```
Rs.MoveFirst
Rs.Move F.Seltop - 1
length = F.Selheight
```

the debugger says that length is 0.

It seems that when I click the Button to open frmtwo it deselects the Records in my Subform. Is that correct? and if so, is there a Way to "remember" the selected Records?

Comment: Identify the IDs of the selected records before you open form2. Then, when opening form2, filter on those IDs.

Comment: What Gustav said. Also, note that when you open another form in dialog mode, the current code (frmOne) freezes until the dialog is closed. If you open frmTwo normally you can work with both (more easily).

Comment: unfortunately it does not work this way; when i click on any field or button in my Mainform, it deselects the records of the subform(which is my problem), my question pertains to how i can stop this happening or if its even possible to do so